# What is involved in making WPF web-based application?

Tags: wpf, web-applications, c#-4.0, e-commerce, xbap

I am developing an eCommerce site as a project for a class and I've only done mostly console application programming.  The site is to use WPF, and is either web-based or mobile (and use Adventure Works db).  I'm not sure what exactly is involved as far as programming technologies.

I became confused as I did some searching and saw terms like .xbap and wcf.  What is the general overview and relationships of the technologies involved to develop a web app that is an eCommerce.

Comment: Silverlight application, you mean?

Comment: I want to say no, but I don't really know much about Silverlight. I just know that it has to be a WPF web-based application. I'm not sure if that means it has to be in a web browser or not.

Comment: Silverlight Out-Of-Browser (OOB) applications could be the answer.

Comment: Aren't Silverlight(inherited or not) and WPF two different technologies?

Comment: Silverlight and WPF are indeed separate technologies, they just share a lot of skills, languages, and such (XAML, for example).  WPF in-browser is called XBAP, and isn't used much because for most folks, Silverlight does it better (since it can run on mac, and thus hit more target audience, and has better media capabilities, often desired in a browser).  Did the class project specify it MUST be WPF?

Comment: Yes, WPF is a must!  Is there a non-browser web-based technology I could use? I glanced around and saw something about WCF, which I know nothing about.

Answer (score 1):

WPF is a technology designed for RDA (Rich Desktop Applications). You can't use it to build a website. Silverlight is a technology designed for RIA (Rich Internet Applications), so it is clearly better for your use.

You told about mobile... What do you mean ? Should your website be used on a mobile device ? In this case, you shouldn't use any of these technology because of interoperability...

If your project MUST be WPF, so you should read about XAML, WPF Binding, MVVM (not mandatory at first, but can helps to design your app).

If you could give us a little more precision about your project, we'll help you more efficiently.

Comment: The project had the restrictions of being a eCommerce WPF web-based or mobile based application.  Is there anything else other than XAML that I should know about?  Like, is LINQ to SQL (we're using adventureworks database) necessary or WCF.